# Numpy: Fastest way to change 10% of all matrix elements

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a matrix `M` of size `m x n`. Currently, if I want to change 10% of all matrix elements in a process, I do the following:

```
M = np.ones((m, n))
for _ in range(999999999):
    M = M + (np.random.random(M.shape) < 0.1) * np.random.random(M.shape)
    # do stuff with M
```

This approach however is really slow many iterations and for large matrices and needs `m*n` random numbers when I really only need `0.1*m*n`.

How can I perform the operation above much faster?

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, you could do it inplace with `M += `

Comment: You can play with profiling other options (like computing a set of indices, then sampling a random number at each, then adding it), but there's no particularly fast way to do this. Anything that reduces how many random numbers you sample will come at the cost of losing the vectorized addition and multiplication.

Comment: In your sample code you start with a matrix of ones. Is this how your production matrix is initially created or is some set of arbitrary numbers?

Comment: @Ethan Normally, I start with a set of random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the values with random indexing if your use case can tolerate an approximate 10% of the values:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((10,10))
a[np.random.rand(*a.shape)>=0.9] = 0.
a
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

As you can see you will get approximately 10 values changed.

Comment: Can I modify each matrix element differently with your approach?

Comment: You can certainly use an array of different values instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

I gave this a crack, and came up with one method that is executing faster on my laptop. I didn't go to 1B iterations though!

Best Performer:

```
%timeit advancedSlice()
9.56 s ± 12.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

def advancedSlice():
    M = np.arange(12000000.0).reshape(1200,10000)
    rows = M.shape[0]
    cols = M.shape[1]
    sampleSize = M.size//10
    for _ in range(100):
        M[np.random.randint(rows, size=sampleSize), np.random.randint(cols, size=sampleSize),] += np.random.random(sampleSize)
    return M
```

2nd best Performer: Using michaelg's method

```
%timeit advancedSlice2()
22.8 s ± 11.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

def advancedSlice2():
    M = np.arange(12000000.0).reshape(1200,10000)

    for _ in range(100):
        randIndecies =np.random.rand(*M.shape)>=0.9
        M[randIndecies] += np.random.random(randIndecies[randIndecies==True].size)
    return M
```

Orginal Code:

```
%timeit randMask()
33.2 s ± 211 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

def randMask():
    M = np.arange(12000000.0).reshape(1200,10000)
    for _ in range(100):
        M = M + (np.random.random(M.shape)  < 0.1) * np.random.random(M.shape)
    return M
```